# Prove that the map $z\mapsto \frac 1 2\left(z+\frac 1 z\right)$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that the map $$f:\Bbb C\setminus D^2\to \Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$$ defined by $$f(z)=\frac 1 2\left(z+\frac 1 z\right)$$ is a homeomorphism, where $D^2$ is the closed unit disk and “$\setminus$” between sets refer to the set difference, without referring to more advanced theorem like Riemann mapping theorem.

Let $w=f(z)$. I started by deducing the definition of $f$ is equivalent of saying $$\left(w-z\right)^2=w^2-1.$$ However, I have trouble deducing which solution would be the inverse for $f$, and I struggle to prove either map is continuous. Is there a neater way I can approach this?

Comment: What is. $\mathbb{D}^2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking that it is a bijection is simple algebra.

Since it's a map from open set to open set, given that that its derivative $f'(z)=\frac{1}{2}(1-1/z^2)$ does not vanish, the inverse must be differentiable at every point as well. This fact should be covered in complex analysis, or in multivariable real analysis.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: If we were given $f$ is bijectively continuous and is an open map, isn’t $f$ automatically a homeomorphism from basic point-set topology? Could you add details of why $f$ is an open map?

Comment: Yes, biject-contin-open map must be homeomorphic. Reason why $f$ is open map is a specific part of the aforementioned Inverse Function Theorem. If $f$ has continuous derivative on an open set $U$ that does not vanish at all, for each $u\in U$ a small enough open neighbourhood of $u$ is necessarily mapped bijectively to an open neighbourhood of $f(u)$. This fact is not obvious and needs to be proven.

Comment: @user108580 forgot to tag you in the comment earlier